# HTML table border and text overflow

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

I'm displaying an HTML table using some CSS as follows.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .style-class {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 20%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
        border: 1px;
    }
</style>

<table rules="all" class="style-class">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>Text overflow ellipsis demo.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>Text overflow ellipsis demo.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Mozilla FireFox (29.0.1) displays it correctly as follows.

[image]

Google Chrome (35.0.1916.153 m) displays it with missing right and bottom borders as can be seen in the following snap shot.

[image]

Internet Explorer (8) displays this table with no borders at all as follows.

[image]

Can this table be displayed with all borders along with `text-overflow:ellipsis` which is important as displayed by FireFox as can be seen in the respective snap shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the overflow and border rules to cells rather than the whole table, you can get the effect you need. Try this CSS:

```
.style-class {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.style-class td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```